# VHDL equivalent for Verilog @(posedge clk)

Tags: vhdl, verilog, fpga

I am not familiar with verilog. I did my best trying to convert it.

While simulating the clock is going from '0' to 'x' which is weird. 
I am suspecting this part to be the problem

```
repeat(9) @(posedge clk);
   DataIn_i <= 1'b1;
   DataIn_q <= 1'b1;
@(posedge clk);
  FillSel <= 1'b0;
  DataIn_i <= 1'b0;
  DataIn_q <= 1'b0;
```

here are links to both benches.

Verilog bench - http://a.pomf.se/fvamqd.v
Vhdl bench - http://a.pomf.se/riolvf.vhd

any input is welcome,thanks in advance.

EDIT: Can anyone please explain the verilog code given above?

Comment: Remove `;` after `@(posedge clk)`.

Answer (score 6):

Translating Verilog's `@posedge clk)` to VHDL depends on where it is located in an always or initial block. If it's the very first construct of the block, you can do

Verilog:

```
always @(posedge signal)
begin
...
end
```

VHDL:

```
process(signal)
begin
  if rising_edge(signal) then  -- Older VHDL if (signal'event and signal = '1')
  ...
  end if;
end process;
```

When embedded in the block, use the `wait until` statement:

```
Verilog: @(posedge clk);
VHDL:    wait until rising_edge(signal);

Verilog:  forever ...
VHDL:     loop ... end loop

Verilog: repeat(n) ...
VHDL:    for i in 1 to n loop ... end loop;
```

Note that when I write ... for Verilog, that is for the single statement that follows, or a single begin/end block that follows.

Comment: That was helpful. Any insight on the clock problem?

Comment: Assuming you know VHDL, what is your clk_process supposed to do the way you have written it?